# Help me find my mistake for the population solution function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**Question**

A pond is initially stocked with 100 fish. It can carry a maximum population of $C=3,500$ fish. The population of fish, $P(t)$, where t is measured in months, grows according to the standard logistic equation:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kp\left(1-\frac{P}{C}\right)$$

Write down the standard form of the solution for P(t),in terms of the variables k, t,and the known values of P(0)and C.

---

**My Answer**

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kp\left(1-\frac{P}{3500}\right)$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP-\frac{kP^2}{3500}$$

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=\frac{3500kP-kP^2}{3500}$$

$$\frac{1}{P(3500k-kP)} dP=\frac{1}{3500} dt$$

$$\left[\frac{\ln P - \ln(3500-P)}{3500k}\right]_{100}^P=\left[\frac{1}{3500}t\right]_0^t$$

$$\frac{\ln P-\ln(3500-P)}{3500k}-\frac{\ln \left(\frac{100}{3400}\right)}{3500k}=\frac{1}{3500}t$$

$$\ln P-\ln (3500-P)+ \ln 34= tk$$

$$\ln \left(\frac{P}{3500-P}\right)=k-\ln 34$$

$$\frac{P}{3500-P}=e^{k-\ln 34}$$

$$P=(3500-P)e^{k-\ln 34}$$

$$P=\frac{3500e^{k-\ln 34}}{1+e^{k-\ln 34}}$$

Unfortunately this is incorrect, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong over here. **Would really appreciate if anyone can shed some light.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dP}{dt}&=kP\left(1-\frac PC\right)=kP\left(\frac{C-P}C\right)\\
\frac{dP}{P(C-P)}&=\frac kC dt\\
\frac 1C\int_{P_0}^P\left(\frac 1P+\frac 1{C-P}\right)&= \frac kC \int_0^tdt\\
\left[\ln \frac P{C-P}\right]_{P_0}^P&=kt\\
\ln\left(\frac{P}{C-P}\cdot\frac{C-P_0}{P_0}\right)&=kt\\
\frac P{C-P}&=\frac{P_0}{C-P_0}e^{kt}\\
\frac PC&=\frac{P_0e^{kt}}{P_0(e^{kt}-1)+C}\\
P&=\frac{CP_0e^{kt}}{P_0(e^{kt}-1)+C}=\frac{P_0e^{kt}}{\frac{P_0}C(e^{kt}-1)+1}
\end{align}$$
Substitute $P_0=100, C=3500$ to arrive at the final answer.
$$\frac{3500e^{kt}}{e^{kt}+34}$$

Comment: You're most welcome. It would probably have been easier to substitute the values of $P_0,C$  in the fourth last line, but here you see the relationship between the variables more clearly before plugging in their values.

Comment: Yep I understand :) will do like this in the future

Comment: For problems like this it's helpful to note that there is a $t$ in the final answer (as it's a function of time) (there was no $t$ in your original answer). It may be helpful to note that  $k, t$ always appear together as $kt$ and usually as $e^{kt}$.

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you did the integration you are wrong.  On the right, $\int \frac 1{3500}dt=\frac 1{3500} \log t + C'$.  Similarly your integration on the left is not correct.  You seem to assume the integrand is constant, so you can multiply the integrand by the length of the interval to get the integral. This is not correct.

Comment: I'm sorry assumed what as the constant?

Comment: When you integrate each side you get a constant.  The difference of them is what you are interested in because you can subtract one of them from each side.. You have a starting condition that gives you that difference.  If you do a definite integral on each side you need to make sure you integrate over the same interval, which you have not justified.

Comment: But isn't it the case that when $t=0, P=100$?

Comment: And correct me if I am wrong $\int \frac{1}{3500t} dt=\frac{1}{3500} \ln t +c$ and $\int \frac{1}{3500} dt=\frac{1}{3500} t +c $

Comment: I thought there was a $t$ in the denominator on the right, but there wasn't, so the integrand is a constant there and you are correct.  You lost a factor  $t$ on the right a couple lines later so your $e^{k-\ln 34}$ should be $e^{k-\ln 34}.  P$ needs to depend on $t$